# Symfony3: Why choices submit key text instead of its value

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Symfony version 3.1.3

I am generating a choices list from the database like bellow and it works fine.

```
class ClassType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('class',
                      EntityType::class,
                      array('class'         => 'PIE10Bundle:Classes',
                            'expanded'      => false,
                            'multiple'      => false,));
        // some other form elements
    }    
}
```

in the web page it gives HTML Select like below,

```
<select name="class[class]" id="class_class">
    <option value="6">1A</option>
    <option value="7">4C</option>
</select>
```

and in the controller, I am getting the submitted data and debug it as below,

```
if( $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() )
{
    $cName  = $form['class']->getData();
    echo $cName;
    die;
}
```

My result is `1A` or `4C` (depending on the selection) but not `6` or `7`.
I am expecting to get the values of the choice list but not its key text.

I wonder how this happens and how to fix this to get the value. Further I have another choice list in the same form but it submits the expected value.

Thanks

Comment: Does `$cName = $form->get("class")->getData();` return the same result?

Comment: yes it returns the same result (which means 1A or 4C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with

```
$cName->getId()
```

I suppose the `$cName` is an istance of the `PIE10Bundle:Classes` entity (try dumping a `get_class($cName)`) and the echo print the name because is implemented as a `__toString` method.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for this :)). `$cName->getId()` gives the expected 6 and 7 values